# Conditional formatting using AND on a range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a fixed cell $I$1 containing the current date.  I have col D whose cells each contain a date.  I also have col F which contains a percentage (there is one of these wherever corresponding col D cell has a date).

The conditional formatting I want is: If date in col D is before date in $I$1 AND percentage in corresponding cell of col F is greater than 0, then set format.

Based on previous answers on this site, I've tried the "=AND(AND(...;...);...)" method as well as the "multiplication method".  Any hints from an expert (since I'm, obviously, not one!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it - For example, supposing you wanted to do this formatting for a cell in row 1:

```
=And($D1 < $I$1, $F1 > 0)
```

Comment: yes, this worked.   I'm so embarrased I didn't figure this out for myself! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it along the lines you suggest and it seems to work OK:

```
=AND(D1<$I$1;E1>0)
```

Is this what you want?

[image]

Comment: yes, that worked great.  I'm so embarrased I didn't figure this out for myself!  Thanks again for the help!